# Ubuntu sendmail "Relaying denied. Ip name possibly forged" (in reply to rcpt to command)

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, email, sendmail

When I try to send an email (from a different server) to a local account on my server I get the following error:

```
Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [W.X.Y.Z]
```

Here's what I do:

```
user@a-different-domain.com:~$ telnet subdomain.domain.com 25
Trying A.B.C.D...
Connected to subdomain.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 subdomain.domain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu1; ...
HELO a-different-domain.com
250 subdomain.domain.com Hello ...
MAIL FROM: <user@a-different-domain.com>
250 2.1.0 <user@a-different-domain.com>... Sender ok
RCPT TO: <user@subdomain.domain.com>
550 5.7.1 <user@subdomain.domain.com>... Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [W.X.Y.Z]
```

The problem is that I can send emails just fine if I use `RCPT TO: <user@mail.subdomain.domain.com>` instead of `RCPT TO: <user@subdomain.domain.com>`

Please see below the configuration that I currently use.

DNS Configuration:

```
Host                 Type  Priority  Redirect to
subdomain.domain.com MX    10        mail.subdomain.domain.com
subdomain.domain.com A     10        A.B.C.D
```

Email server configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu
Email Server: sendmail
```

In /etc/mail/access I have (among others):

```
mail.subdomain.domain.com
subdomain.domain.com
```

/etc/mail/local-host-names:

```
localhost
mail.subdomain.domain.com
subdomain.domain.com
```

Regarding the masquerading here is what I have in /etc/mail/sendmail.mc:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`subdomain.domain.com')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`subdomain.domain.com.')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
```

Just for clarifications: mail.subdomain.domain.com and subdomain.domain.com point to the same IP address.

================= UPDATE1 =================

@Andrzej A. Filip

Yes, i restarted sendmail.

Here is the output of `echo '$=w' | sendmail -Am -bt`:

```
root@subdomain:/etc/mail# echo '$=w' | sendmail -Am -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> [A.B.C.D]
mail.subdomain.domain.com
[ip6-loopback]
localhost
subdomain
ip6-localhost
[127.0.0.1]
[127.0.0.2]
subdomain.domain.com
[ip6-localhost]
ip6-loopback
```

================= UPDATE2 =================

I tested and found out (without changing the DNS configuration) that if i add subdomainXXX.domain.com (where subdomainXXX is any string) to /etc/mail/local-host-names and then I test sending an email from a  remote server it simply works:

```
user@remote-server:/# telnet subdomain.domain.com 25
Trying A.B.C.D...
Connected to subdomain.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 subdomain.domain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu1; ...
HELO remote-server
250 subdomain.domain.com Hello ....
MAIL FROM: <...>
250 2.1.0 <...>... Sender ok
RCPT TO: <root@subdomainXXX.domain.com>
250 2.1.5 <root@subdomainXXX.domain.com>... Recipient ok
```

So it works for any subdomain except for the one that I'm interested into (subdomain.domain.com - which is actually the hostname of the server).

Comment: Can you also provide us with the contents of `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Here's the content of /etc/hosts:
`::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost subdomain.domain.com
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
A.B.C.D subdomain.domain.com  subdomain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And .. after several hours I found the issue:

`localhost.localdomain` needs to be put alongside with `subdomain.domain` in `/etc/mail/local-host-names`.

So, the correct content for `/etc/mail/local-host-names` should be:

```
localhost
localhost.localdomain
subdomain.domain.com
```

It does **NOT WORK** if you only use:

```
localhost
subdomain.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`"Relaying denied"`suggets that sendmail at mail.subdomain.domain.com does not treat subdomain.domain.com as a local email domain, email domain hosted by it.

Have you restarted/reloaded sendmail server after modifying /etc/mail/local-host-name file at mail.subdomain.domain.com host?

YES=> What is reported by the command below exececuted by root at mail.subdomain.domain.com host?

```
echo '$=w' | sendmail -Am -bt
```

Comment: I replied to your comment in my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Could you double check lack of mistakes in masquerading real DNS/host names? Are subdomain.domain.com and mail.subdomain.domain.com different host? You want mail.subdomain.domain.com handle email for subdomain.domain.com and complain that subdomain.domain.com refuses email for eail domain it should not handle as local. BTW /etc/mail/access requires "KEY VALUE" line format and makemap compilation.

Comment: 1. subdomain.domain.com and mail.subdomain.domain.com point to the same IP.  
  
2. I don't want mail.subdomain.domain.com to handle emails for subdomain.domain.com - I would like for subdomain.domain.com to handle emails on its own (but I just didn't know how to set up MX records differently). So, from my point of view I don't even need mail.subdomain.domain.com.

Comment: In theory you would not need MX record at all. In practice some mail servers are picky about email with sender from domain/host without MX record. Try to eliminate mail.subdomain.domain.com fro DNS - `subdomain.domain.com MX 10 subdomain.domain.com`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. I updated the DNS records but I believe I have to wait up until to one hour. Still, do you think could help? I see it more like local thing: for some reason sendmail does not see itself as subdomain.domain.com (even though it is configured in local-host-names).

Comment: Still doesn't work after the DNS change:

nslookup | type=mx | subdomain.domain.com | Non-authoritative answer: subdomain.domain.com mail exchanger = 10 subdomain.domain.com.

Comment: what is reported by the folowing test command executed by root: `sendail -bv root@subdomain.domain.com` ?

Comment: Here's the output of sendmail -bv root@subdomain.domain.com:
root@subdomain.domain.com... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host localhost.localdomain., user root@localhost.localdomain

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7930/discussion-between-razvan-and-andrzej-a-filip)

Comment: As you "reply to your own question" suggests you have fixed the problem. In short: sendmail had changed subdomain.domain.com into localhost.localdomain (based on /etc/hosts entries).

Comment: But this does not explain why email gets rejected by the Relay_ok rule set (This is where the failure message gets generated)

Comment: @adamo The chain of rule set calls is pretty long: check_rcpt > checkrcpt [FEATURE(delay_cheks)] > Basic_check_rcpt > Rcpt_ok > ParseRecipient > CanonAddr > canonify > Canonify2 **REWRITE HERE**

Comment: It is exactly the rewrite that bugs me. Could it be that because subdomain.domain.com has two entries in /etc/hosts of which 127.0.0.1 is the first one, that it gets "overwritten" by localhost.localdomain somewhere in the process before the rule sets are applied?

Comment: @adamo IMHO It is quite likely that /etc/hosts entries caused the rewrite in "host" map lookup in Canonify2 rule set.

Comment: @Razvan Could you post results of the following command executed by root? 'echo "/map host subdomain.domain.com" | sendmail -bt'

Comment: Please note that in the mean time (since I had the problem solved) I made a couple of changes to the server so, assuming that these did not affect the output of the command (I don't think they did because the output below seems to reflect the exact issue I was facing - and at this point if i remove localhost.localdomain i still get the same issue), here's the result: 
`> map_lookup: host (subdomain.domain.com) returns localhost.localdomain. (0)`

Comment: The important fact is that a rewrite happens [Most likely it had been different one before your changes].

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at my sendmail.cf. The error message that you give `Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged` happens in the `Relay_ok` rule set. `Relay_ok` is executed by `Basic_check_rcpt`, which in turn is executed by `checkrcpt` which in turn is executed by `check_rcpt` (confusing, I know). The error happens when the value for `$&{client_resolve}` is FORGED which means that the forward lookup does not match the reverse DNS lookup.

So the question is: If all you change is either including or removing `localhost.localdomain` from `/etc/mail/local-host-names`, why does `Relay_ok` rejects or accepts email based on this fact?  The interesting lines in `Relay_ok` is:

```
SRelay_ok
R$*                     $: $&{client_addr}
:
R$*                     $: < $&{client_resolve} >
```

When localhost.localdomain is not included in `/etc/mail/local-host-name` we get a `<FORGED>` reply from `$&{client_resolve}`. When it is included, we do not get this. So the decision about relaying happens before calling `Relay_ok`. This means that `Rcpt_ok` (again called in `Basic_check_rcpt` before `Relay_ok`) decides that.

Now from the description that the OP gives, Ubuntu sendmail seems to not automatically include names in `/etc/hosts` into $=w and that is why localhost.localdomain needs to be included specifically. But why?

[ Had the original poster posted the complete sendmail.mc it would have helped a lot ]

Comment: I put the complete sendmail.mc on PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/a5nX62FB